# R shiny downloadHandler- write.xlsx: invalid 'path' argument

Tags: r, shiny

I've been trying to write my first small shiny app that takes two .xlsx files and do inner_join (like SQL would do) and then let's you download the result .xlsx. But when I try to download the file, I get error message that says:

```
    Error in path.expand(file) : invalid 'path' argument
    Warning: Error in path.expand: invalid 'path' argument
```

Here is my ui.R:

```
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel('A linker'),
  sidebarPanel(
        fileInput("data","Choose file"),
        textInput('d_sheet','Write the name of the sheet to be modified',
                  value = "", placeholder = "e.g. List 1"),
        textInput('d_col','Write the ID-number of column that contains the ID'),
        fileInput("libr","Choose library"),
        textInput("l_sheet","Write the name of sheet that contains the data",
                  value="",placeholder="e.g. List 1"),
        textInput("l_col","write the ID-number of column that contains the ID"),
        textInput("l_join","Write the ID-number of columns to be linked to the
                  file")
  ),
  mainPanel(
        p('This application allows you to link data from the LIBRARY to
          the data of the FILE. FILE is the table to be enhanced by the new data,
          LIBRARY is the source of the data.'),
        downloadButton("dwnld_data",label ="Download"))))
```

and server.R:

```
shinyServer( function(input, output){
  options(shiny.maxRequestSize = 9*1024^2)
  res_file<-reactive({
        input_File <- input$data#
        file_sheet<-input$d_sheet#
        file_col<-as.vector(input$d_col)#
        lib_File<-input$libr#
        lib_sheet<-input$l_sheet#
        lib_col<-as.vector(input$l_col)#
        lib_data<-as.vector(input$l_join)#

        a_file<-read.xlsx(input_File,sheetName = file_sheet)
        colnames(a_file)[1:file_col]<-"a"
        colnames(a_file)[file_col:ncol(a_file)]<-"b"
        colnames(a_file)[file_col]<-"ID"

        l_file<-read.xlsx(lib_File,sheetName=lib_sheet)
        tab_l<-l_file[,c(lib_col,lib_data)]
        colnames(l_file)<-"ID"
        r_file<-inner_join(a_file,l_file,by="ID")
        r_file})

  output$dwnld_data <- downloadHandler(
        filename = function() {paste("result.xlsx")},
        content = function(file) {
              write.xlsx(res_file(),file, sheetName="List 1")
        })})
```

It's nothing fancy, more like my first experiment. I have tried to find solution to this error for several hours and red a lot of articles, so I am very sorry, if I ask you something, that has been already answered, I haven't found it.
All I have found and tried:

- update R Studio (no effect)
- try to first write the file into some temporary dir and then load it back (no effect)

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I don't think the issue is with the `downloadHandler` (you could try this by replacing `res_file()` with `mtcars` in your `write.xlsx` statement and see if it works). In your `res_file` code, try replacing `input_File <- input$data` by `input_File <- input$data$datapath`. `input$data` is a dataframe with a bunch of columns [see here](http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/fileInput.html).